# Finding self-answered questions

Tags: feature-request, self-answer

I have quite a few questions that I've answered myself - usually with extra commands to get to the conclusion required, in order to help other visitors.

I'm trying to find one in particular on Super User, but I'm having trouble finding it in my list of questions that have +1 votes or more on them.

Is there a search term or page that shows all the questions I've asked, and self-answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with the built-in search but if you can live with the fact that [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is only updated once a week, the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/518525?UserId=24010) should answer your question:

```sql
select q.id as [Post Link]
     , q.score [q-score]
     , q.creationdate [q-created]
     , a.score [a-score]
     , a.creationdate [a-created]
from posts q
inner join posts a on a.parentid = q.id
where q.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
and q.owneruserid = a.owneruserid
and q.owneruserid = ##userid:int?24010##
and exists 
 (select 1 
  from votes v 
  where v.postid in (q.id, a.id)
  and v.votetypeid = 2  -- upmod
  )
```